# How do you say in Latin: Thank you to all my patreons?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I saw in a video someone thanking all their patreons by saying:

> GRATIAS AGO OMNIBUS PATRONIS MEIS.

But isn't 'OMNIBUS PATRONIS MEIS' ablative? Does it makes sense?

Comment: As mentioned, dative. More importantly, Latin isn't English. It'd've been far more idiomatic to move the verb to the end or (in this case) omit it and the possessive.

Comment: "Patreon" is a modern company trademark.  I think you mean "patrons" in the title, not "patreons".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's dative, not ablative. In the plural, ablative and dative are identical, so you'll have to only guess from context which is which.

The only thing that could be added is that often the indirect objects go before the verbs in sentences like these. You can find [gratias tibi ago](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=gratias+tibi+ago) and [tibi gratias ago](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=tibi+gratias+ago) but **not** [gratias ago tibi](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=gratias+ago+tibi) or [gratias ago tibi](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=ago+gratias+tibi).

Comment: Ugh. Right! Newbie mistake 